# How to check if a ship sank in battleship game java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, methods

I start to create battleship game in java. I have 5 ships with length 5,4,3,3,2 and an array `int gameBoard[][] = new int[10][10];` where i put the ships. I also create an array `boolean BoardHits[][]= new boolean[10][10];` where i check the hits of the player.
Now i want to create a method  `boolean getBoardStrike(int[] hit)` which takes as parameter a position and adds a hit at BoardHits array if this position has not been hitted again. If we hit a ship the we must check if all ship positions hitted(ship sank). Are there any efficient way to implement this? 
(When i put a ship in the array gameBoard i put the ship id, so if i a ship with length 5 in the board i have 5 cells with the number 5).

```
public boolean getBoardStrike(int[] hit) {
    boolean flag = true;
    if (boardHits[hit[0]][hit[1]] = false) {
        hits[hit[0]][hit[1]] = true;
        //check if the whole ship is hitted
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you determine what a ship is?

Comment: Call `myShip.isFloating()`

Comment: when i put a ship in the board, i put the ship id. For example if i put a ship with length 4 in the gameBoard i will have 4 cells with 4 4 4 4. So i know what kind of ship is

Comment: It sounds like you need to do more view-model extraction, including creation of a Ship class, classes whose instances populate the board, which have a `public boolean hit(int x, int y)` method, and a `isFloating()` method. When a hit attempt occurs, iterate through a `List<Ship>` find out if a ship has been hit, and then call its `isFloating()` method.

Comment: @LeeYaan Ok, so, you need to compare the `board` with the `hits` and determine of the occupied space of `hits` covers all the "ship" on `board` - me, personally, I have a "ship" object, which contained the "hits".  I'd use the board to determine where each ship is and the direction they are pointing - much simpler - but that's me

Comment: Yeah, what he ^^^^^^^^^^^^ said

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer, i'll try to implement your idea

Answer (score 0):

I would try more object oriented approach since Java is object-oriented language:

```
public interface Battleship {
    public void hit(Point shot);
    public List<Point> getCoordinates();
    public boolean isSinked();
}

public class BattleshipPart {
    private boolean hit;
    private Point coordinate;

    // getters and setters 
}

public abstract class AbstractBattleship implements Battleship {

    // these are for direction in constructors
    public static int NORTH = 1;
    public static int EAST = 2;
    public static int SOUTH = 3;
    public static int WEST = 4;

    protected List<BattleshipPart> parts;

    public void hit(Point shot) {
        return parts.stream()
            .findFirst(part -> part.coordinate.equals(shot))
            .ifPresent(part -> part.setHit(true));
    }

    public List<Point> getCoordinates() {
        return parts.stream()
            .map(part -> part.getCoordinate())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public boolean isSinked() {
        return parts.stream()
            .allMatch(BattleshipPart::isHit);
    }
}

public final class SmallBattleship extends AbstractBattleship {

    public SmallBattleship(Point start, int direction) {
        // create parts or throw exception if parameters weren't valid
    }
}
```

New ship types are created just by extending `AbstractBattleship` and just creating new parts in constructor.